# Highlight cells based on some criteria related column and rows to another table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have two worksheets: the first one is **main** (Table 1) and the second is the **report** (Table 2) generated from values in two columns in the main table. When the conditional formatting is triggered the cell in Table 2 is highlighted:

[image: tabel 1]

[image: tabel 2]

In Table 1, the primary key is a compound key combining `id`-`year` columns.
In Table 2, the report checks whether the related column-row exists in Table 1 and if so the cell is to be highlighted.

How I can achieve it using conditional formatting?

I've some steps that will converted to conditional formatting in cell below:

1. In selected cell, the paired value year-id from table 2 will be
   looked up in Table 1 in the relevant column pairing.
2. If the related paired-value exists, the cell in Table 2 is highlighted (the color differs between `id`s) and if not it won't be highlighted.

For Step 1. I can't find the right formula. If there is another solution I'll considered it.

Can Step 2. be achieved with VBA and if so, how?

---

[updated]
Based on pnuts's suggestion, the problems above I can achieve with some modification to get vary color but recently I get different format value that appear in table 1 that look like "2003-2004". In second table, the related column (2003 & 2004) must be highlighted.
How I can check "-" sign then highlight two related columns?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Table1` and `Table2` are both in Cell B2, one way is to put `=Sheet1!C5&Sheet1!D5` in your `Table2` sheet in A5 and copy down until a cell appears blank, then apply CF to `=$C$6:$M$11` with this rule:

```
=MATCH($B6&C$5,$A:$A,0)>0
```

This would only apply one colour throughout (which may be less confusing than 5 or more) but I take it you know how to break this down into separate rules for different colours by restricting the range for each to one row at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but when I try the formula that you suggested it doesn't work but when I try modify become this 
=match($b6,c$5,0)>0 it works.
Then, how I can simplify for some redundant ids become unique like table 2?

Comment: this is what I've achieved 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1LSDWOt7AGILV9QNlp2UEQ1cjQ/edit?usp=sharing
cross purposes?

Comment: After I try again, your suggestion is work well and for the last experiment I work with different step with what you've describe.
Now, I'll work around about the colour. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I get it but recently I've got different format value that appear look like I describe above (new). So, if the new condition meets the 2 years coloumn must be highlighted.

Comment: Sir, I can't understand with Accept term in this part "I suggest you remove your Accept ... ".